# remove the forward slash from ls in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I really tried it a lot, I know how sed works,

But I have a file, say `ls -t -d */`
which gives me

```
15072301/
15072300/
15072223/
15072222/
15072221/
```

Basically I want to get rid of this / in the end of each line. Using sed itself? I know I can handle it otherwise too, like taking a substring but there has to be an sed answer to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sed` way to remove a trailing slash from each line would be

```
sed 's:/$::' file
```

Notice that `ls` is actually not providing any value here, assuming the directory names correspond to when they were last modified. The shell will expand the glob in sorted order. So you might as well use

```
printf '%s\n' */ | sort -r | sed 's:/$::'
```

You should generally not use `ls` in scripts. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a discussion.

Comment: "newline"? Do you mean "forward slash"?